# AES-GCM with arbitrary tag length

Tags: java, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

For algorithm test vector evaluation, I am trying to perform an AES in GCM mode for encryption and decryption with arbitrary tag length values such as 32 bits.

When I try to initialize my cipher with such an arbitrary tag length as follows:

```
final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(tagLen, iv);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
```

I am met with this error:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Unsupported TLen value; must be one of {128, 120, 112, 104, 96}
```

Normally, this would be a good thing, because you don't want a tag length of 32. However, for my purposes I do need this tag length.

Is there a way that I can override these restrictions to allow for arbitrary tag lengths?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use short tag lengths with GCM; in addition to the obvious weakness of someone being able to generate a forgery with probability $2^{-32}$, if someone were to find a forgery to a nonce used to encrypt a message, they can use that to generate other forgeries.  This is specific to GCM (and similar algorithms, such as (I believe) Poly1305).  Is there a reason you can't use (say) HMAC or CMAC, which doesn't have this cavaet?

Comment: 100% agreed, which is why I put this in the question: "Normally, this would be a good thing, because you don't want a tag length of 32. However, for my purposes I do need this tag length.".  

Since these are test vectors, I need to make sure that I use libraries that test the proper backends, in this case JCE.  I need to specifically test the AESGCM algorithm for this library.

Comment: A bit technical, however, a dupe of this ; [What are the constraints on using GCM with a tag size of 96 and 128 bits?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27374/18298). Message size and the number of messages are important to decide. You need to edit the library or find one to achieve 32-bit tag length ( that is off-topic here).

Comment: @poncho missing "AES/HMAC/NoPadding"

Answer (score 3):

The Bouncy Castle library was created to support many algorithms in software, with the caveat that it let's you shoot yourself in the foot if you really want to.

I can run the above code with tag size 32 without issue:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[16], "AES");

final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC");
GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(32, new byte[16]);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
cipher.update("Maarten did it".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byte[] ct = cipher.doFinal();
```

Note that the error can be seen e.g. [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/CipherCore.java). As you can see that is the internal implementation of AES/GCM in the **provider**, not e.g. `Cipher`. You may have found that out by looking at the full stacktrace...

Comment: `shoot yourself in the foot` :)

Comment: Well, the NIST recommendation for GCM does allow for a 32-bit MAC under some circumstances. If one follows the guidelines for short tags described in that document, I don't see why one couldn't use it.

Comment: In case the authentication tag accumulates several input blocks, there might be a valid discussion on how to choose it's length dependent on the input length.